# The $k$_th coefficient of the polynomial :$f_n(z)f_m(jz)+f_m(z)f_n(jz) $

Tags: functions, polynomials, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Let $j=e^{2i\pi/3}$  ( $i$ is the complex number $i^2=-1$), and let :
$$f_n(z)=(1+z)^n$$

> **Question** Is there an expression (without using sums) of the $k$_th coefficient of the following polynomial :$$f_n(z)f_m(jz)+f_m(z)f_n(jz) $$

Comment: Try first solving this with $j = -1$.

Comment: when $n=m$ it' s easy but i don't really know know can i generalize it, $n=m$ gives $0$ if $r$ is odd $(-1)^k\left(_k^n\right)$ when r=2k